# Is mariadb-java-client 2.2.3 compatible with MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mariadb

I'm using mariadb-java-client 2.2.3 to connect to a MySQL server 8.0.11.  I'm also using spring-boot 2.0.2. for the application.
On application startup, I'm getting the following execption:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: (conn=9) Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:198) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:334) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbStatement.java:505) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.getTransactionIsolation(MariaDbConnection.java:859) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
```

According to the MySQL link below, the system variable 'tx_isolation' that was previously deprecated has now been removed.  'transaction_isolation' should be used instead.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-3.html

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no workaround for the moment. Issue has been created on https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-604 to handle that for next version 2.2.5.

Currently, MySQL 8.0 is not supported (some tests even freeze the server), so waiting version to be more stable (and a working docker image to test properly with CI).

Answer (score 3):

For people who switch from MySql to MariaDb on their existing SpringBoot project, and face the same issue:

Upgrading mariadb-java-client to 2.6.0+, in your pom.xml solve the issue (most tutorial on the net has 2.1).